# Symfony2 KnpMenuBundle - Following tutorial and came across this error

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

I followed this tutorial:

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation

And have come across the following error:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "page_show" as such route does not exist.") in /var/www/bundles/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig at line 4.`

Is there a step I am missing here to pass something to a controller?

**From link:**

```
use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class Builder extends ContainerAware
{
public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
{
    $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

    $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'));
    $menu->addChild('About Me', array(
        'route' => 'page_show',
        'routeParameters' => array('id' => 42)
    ));
    // ... add more children

    return $menu;
}
}
```

To actually render the menu, just do the following from anywhere in any Twig template:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('AcmeDemoBundle:Builder:mainMenu') }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tutorial exactly, this error is caused by line 25 in the file

```
2  // src/Acme/MainBundle/Menu/MenuBuilder.php
   ...
25         $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'));
```

The tutorial code assumes that you have a route called 'homepage'. Assuming you set this up inside a custom Bundle, then a quick way to solve this problem so you can get the tutorial up and running is to go to...

```
// src/Acme/MainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
```

...and copy the homepage route from there (will look something like acme_main_bundle_homepage)

Answer (score 1):

Do a `./app/console router:debug` - it will show you all the routes registered in your application. I am guessing page_show is not one of them.

The documentation you are using probably expects you to add your own routes/pages to the menu like this:

```
$menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'homepage'));
```

Where 'homepage' has to already exist. So does 'show_page'. So you need a controller somewhere that handles a request to the show_page route, or exchange show_page for a route that you have already defined in your app. Hope I made sense.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I figured. It doesn't say anywhere what I need to pass into the controller? Do I need to call mainMenu in there?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then no. Your controllers are not concerned about the main menu at all. Simply call `{{ knp_menu_render('AcmeDemoBundle:Builder:mainMenu') }}` in any template where you want the menu to appear.

Comment: Looks like I'll need to tinker with it.